# How to get all project's paths in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink

Is there any way to get all projects paths in eclipse.

e.g

In Eclipse project/package explorer window i have 100 projects.Some of them located in workspace and some aren't(may be some other drives but outside of workspace).
I want to get all projects path,names and write in text file for future references located in package explorer window.
Is there any way to do that.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you willing to write an Eclipse plug-in?

Comment: @E-Riz first i want to know does any one do that already if not i am willing to develop it,In which you can save all projects path in textfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this using:

```java
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

IProject [] projects = workspace.getRoot().getProjects();

for (IProject project : projects)
 {
   IPath path = project.getLocation();

   String pathString = path.toOSString();

   ....
 }
```

Note: This code must be in a plugin or Eclipse headless application, it will not work in an ordinary Java program.